# Получить доченрий элемент JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть следующий код:

```
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' border='0' class='listview'>
  <tr class="b">
    <td class="c">Один</td>
    <td class="c">Два</td>
    <td class="c">Три</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
    <td class="c">Один</td>
    <td class="c">Два</td>
    <td class="c">Три</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
    <td class="c">Один</td>
    <td class="c">Два</td>
    <td class="c">Три</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
   alert(tables[0].childNodes.length);//Возвращает 2
   alert(tables[0].children.length);//Возвращает 1
</script>
```

Почему alert в первом случаи возвращает 1 а в втором 2? Как мне добраться до класса 2-ого td у 2-ого tr?(понимаю что класс можно получить .getAttribute('class') интересует как по цепочке от элемента table добраться до нужного td элемента используя children и chaildNodes). В чём разница childread и chaildNodes?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.listview tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').className`

Comment: `children` учитывает теги, а `childNodes` также учитывает ещё комментарии и текст. В данном примере получается: один тег `<tbody>` (автоматически подставляется некоторыми браузерами) и один текст (перевод строки и несколько пробелов между `<table>` и `<tr>`)

Comment: Благодарю, что пояснили отличие 2-х методов. Можете ли ещё сказать а если уже получена нужная таблица в переменную. И всё таки как от tables[0] добраться до нужного элемента. Просто хочу понять как последовательно до него добраться, потому что мало ли пригодится.

Comment: Составлять и проверять путь до нужной `td` мне, признаться, было лень, но если скрестить `tables[0]` с комментарием DiD, то должно получиться что-то типа `tables[0].querySelector("tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)")`. С `children` (и тем более с `childNodes`) муторно получится - надо будет вручную отфильтровывать элементы (например, по `tagName`)

Comment: Суть в том что для меня удивительно что childNodes и children возвращают меньшее число результатов чем 3. С помощью их вообще возможно решить эту задачу. tables[0].cells тоже не приводит к результату.

Comment: "меньшее число результатов чем 3" - если бы не добавлялся тег `tbody`, их и было бы 3+. А так получается, что если идти через `children`, то у `table` надо сначала выбрать child-a `tbody`, а затем уже у него - child-a нужного `tr`. А, по-хорошему, ещё нужно будет учесть браузеры, которые не подставляют сами `tbody` (и в которых, соответственно, `tr`-ы действительно будут children-ами у `table`). В общем, много мороки. Через `querySelector` и `rows[].cells[]` выходит намного проще

Answer (score 1):

> Как мне добраться до класса 2-ого td у 2-ого tr?

```
tables[0].rows[1].cells[1]
```

```html
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' border='0' class='listview'>
  <tr class="b">
    <td class="c">Один 1</td>
    <td class="c">Два 1</td>
    <td class="c">Три 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
    <td class="c">Один 2</td>
    <td class="c">Два 2</td>
    <td class="c">Три 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
    <td class="c">Один 3</td>
    <td class="c">Два 3</td>
    <td class="c">Три 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
  console.log(tables[0].rows[1].cells[1].getAttribute("class"), tables[0].rows[1].cells[1].textContent);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Посоветовал бы использовать:

```
let rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr")
rows.forEach((elR,indR)=>{
  //ТУТ твой код
})
```